# Navigate to div below or above current div with animation Jquery? JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, html, find

I have a web site and I have made it so each page is vertically below/above each other. on the same page. I would like to put some arrow buttons on the top and the bottom of the screen so once you click it it either animates up to the div above it (if you hit the button on the top of the screen) or animates to the the div below it (if you hit the button on the bottom.)

I'm using a class of min-height 100% on each of the divs and currently have three divs.

I feel like this shouldn't be something too difficult. If you could help me out that would be wonderful. Thank you.

I made a little picture to help be a little more descriptive. Should give you a complete idea for what i'm looking for. ;) http://i45.tinypic.com/s49ugw.jpg

Comment: What have you tried so far?  If the user should also be allowed to scroll manually, you might consider the `scrollTo` pluggin.

Comment: Yeah, they would be allowed to scroll manually. All though it wouldn't be a big concern to me if they wern't able to. 

I've looked into the scrollto but the only problem is i'm terrible with Jquery/Javascript. :/

Comment: figurd it out! thanks! used to the ScrollTo. ;)

Comment: In which case ould you please post an answer, that way your question might be useful for future visitors. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    function scroll(direction) {

        var scroll, i,
                positions = [],
                here = $(window).scrollTop(),
                collection = $('.part');

        collection.each(function() {
            positions.push(parseInt($(this).offset()['top'],10));
        });

        for(i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
            if (direction == 'next' && positions[i] > here) { scroll = collection.get(i); break; }
            if (direction == 'prev' && i > 0 && positions[i] >= here) { scroll = collection.get(i-1); break; }
        }

        if (scroll) {
            $.scrollTo(scroll, {
                duration: 350       
            });
        }

        return false;
    }

    $("#next,#prev").click(function() {        
        return scroll($(this).attr('id'));        
    });

    $(".scrolltoanchor").click(function() {
        $.scrollTo($($(this).attr("href")), {
            duration: 350
        });
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: If anyone has any questions i'll try to go into further detail about the script